# SQL server restore and user permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, restore

I need to permission a user to a database right after a database restore.
I tried this:

```
Use [master]
go

restore database DBTest  
from disk='E:\userTemp\DBTest1.bak'  
WITH MOVE 'DBTest' TO 'E:\SQLData\DBTest1.mdf',
MOVE 'DBTest_log' TO 'F:\SQLData\DBTest1.ldf',
replace, recovery, stats=5, maxtransfersize=1048576
Print '---------------------------RESTORE COMPLETED ---------------------------'

-- Create the user.
CREATE USER [user_indi] FOR LOGIN [user_indi]
GO

USE [DBTest]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'user_indi'
GO
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

> Msg 15023, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>   User, group, or role 'user_indi' already exists in the current database.
>   Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 75
>   User or role 'user_indi' does not exist in this database.

So, what added the command to remove the user in the middle. Now it looks like this.

```
Use [master]
go

restore database DBTest  
from disk='E:\userTemp\DBTest1.bak'  
WITH MOVE 'DBTest' TO 'E:\SQLData\DBTest1.mdf',
MOVE 'DBTest_log' TO 'F:\SQLData\DBTest1.ldf',
replace, recovery, stats=5, maxtransfersize=1048576
Print '---------------------------RESTORE COMPLETED ---------------------------'

-- Remove the user
USE [DBTest]
GO

DROP USER [user_indi]
GO

-- Create the user.
CREATE USER [user_indi] FOR LOGIN [user_indi]
GO

USE [DBTest]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'user_indi'
GO
```

Now, I get the error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot drop the user 'user_indi', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I can't allow errors as I need to schedule this restore and permission job. Why am I getting this error and how can I workaround it?

RM

Comment: Your `USE [DBTest]` statements are in two different places.  In the first one, you're attempting to create the user in MASTER.  In the second one, you're creating it in DBTest.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!. I am not sure how I can make this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `USE [DBTest]` statements are in two different places.

In the first one, you're attempting to create the user in MASTER. In the second one, you're creating it in DBTest.